# Input min max not allow special character in react js

Tags: reactjs, validation, input, jsfiddle

Please point me to sample where i can validate min and max character also none of the special character to be allowed for a input box in react js

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
input.oninput = () => console.log(input.checkValidity());
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="input" type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" />
</form>
```

You can use the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#pattern) attribute to validate that the input only contains characters from particular character sets. The example above only allows 1 or more alphanumeric characters. Pressing "enter" when the input is empty or contains any other character should cause the browser to report a validity error. Moreover, you can use the [`checkValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/checkValidity) method to validate the input in JavaScript.